# WebScriptObject JS function callback

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit, webview

The `WebKit` frameworks' `WebView` class has a property to access the current `WebScriptObject`. I know that you can invoke JS methods using this object, but is there a way to receive asynchronous JS callback notifications?

I want to render something in the `WebView` and the script has a callback function when it finishes, but how do I get this notification back to my Cocoa app (without polling a `var`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `WebScripting` protocol which allows you to vend methods of Cocoa classes as functions in the JavaScript environment in the WebView. Have a read of [the docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html)

You can also use `JavaScriptCore` as you outlined.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out myself.

It should be possible by using the `JavaScriptCore` framework and by creating an `JSObjectRef` with `JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback` and pass a C callback function to this constructor.